# how to understand each part of the name of a parquet file

Tags: apache-spark, parquet

Case:
`part-00000-deb4a3d4-d8c3-4983-8756-ad7e0b29e780.c000.snappy.parquet`

I can't find some rules of a parquet file in the code.
could someone explain?

code:
https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/FileFormatWriter.scala

https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/internal/io/FileCommitProtocol.scala

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this case:

part-00000 signifies Split (of a) Partition number.

-deb4a3d4-d8c3-4983-8756-ad7e0b29e780 signifies random UUID to allow concurrent write processes in Spark Actions that do not conflict.

"c000" signifies a counter indicating the number of times a file has been written for this partition. here is it is zero and it counts on. Not sure what happens if 999  exceeded, to be honest.

Comment: Yes, I read some answers like yours. But I want to see and prove it right in the code way.

Comment: I mean that I want to see the concrete implements in the code but I didn't find it.

Comment: you mean DataFrameWriter in spark source?

Comment: I find it. It is said in the function newTaskTempFile in FileCommitProtocol.scala

Comment: So if you found, then from observation I think what is stated in my answer is correct. There is also another aspect, but that was not in your example.

Comment: yes. your answer is correct. Thank for summary in words